Upgrade HDD to SSD - RAID 1
I will upgrade a RAID 1 with 2 HDDs to a RAID 1 with 2 SSDs on a Dell T420 server (PERC H310).
But first I'd like to make some tests with a new OS installation on this new RAID 1 with SSDs.
Can I take off HDDs without delete virtual disk from them, create a new virtual disk with the news SSDs, make tests, take off SSDs and, put back the HDDs without any lost of functionality, as if nothing had happened?
Other question, which is better, take HDDs off first and then create a new virtual disk with SSDs into server or put SSDs, create a virtual disk and then take HDDs off from server?
Thanks

create a backup and test it

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Yes, you can. The safe way is to create backup dump and experiment, as suggested in the comment. This is also a recommended way.
If you like to play with the danger of becoming fired and unemployed because you just destroyed important business data1, you can do the following: power off the server and switch disks, then power on. On boot there will be a warning that array disappeared; accept that. Do whatever you want. When you desire to return back you switch disks back. You'll see that warning again, but old disks should now show up as having foreign configuration (which means, contain configuration that doesn't correspond to the configuration in controller's NVRAM — because NVRAM was changed since these disks were there last time). Import them, which will return you access to the old array on these disks.

As to about the order of operations. In principle, if you have spare unoccupied slots and proper volume management (LVM, etc) in an installed system, you could migrate without downtime. For that, hot plug new disks, assemble RAID from them from an OS (using megacli), then prepare the partitioning of the new array, use volume management tools to migrate system there and setup boot from the new volume. Then, destroy old volume and hot unplug old disks. I did this many times. This generic recipe can be found in a more verbose form on ServerFault, I'm too lazy to search myself.

1 Not quite; in many cases it still can be recovered. I once deleted a RAID10 array where OS was residing by mistake; it went panic, of course. It was on a LSI MegaRAID controller (Dell PERC is a rebranded MegaRAID, so "the same as yours"). Then I booted the live system and just created the array back without initialization and all of the contents appeared as if nothing happened. But the lesson I learned is that I shouldn't give up, not that I can do this routinely.

Could I do the following scenario (Remembering that I can shutdown the system as many times as I want)?
Server has spare unoccupied slots.
Insert the new disks without removing old ones, create a new virtual disk, install a new system and use as dual boot?
When all tests are made, I'll decide if to come back to the old system or maintain the new one.
Is this scenario possible?

Yes, you can. If you need reinstall, that'll I consider the best approach. On the other hand, backup won't hurt, and it's better than sorry.
